# .net crossthreading trouble

Tags: .net, multithreading

i have such code, in callback function

```
try{
     text.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => text.AppendText("test"))); 
    }
catch (Exception e)
        {
            text.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => text.AppendText(e.Message)));
        }
```

text is winforms.textbox
and at the text.Invoke.. i have "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.CrossThreadMessagingException"
why? this way always worked for me.

Comment: Did you perhaps *create* any UI controls on background threads?

Comment: Simply, there is nothing obvious there that should cause this - so it sounds like something is odd *outside* the code we can see. I'm wondering if the problem is where/how `text` is created. But very hard to tell just from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `//blahblahblah` does something that talks to one or more UI controls? Maybe to read/write values? That won't work, due to *thread affinity*. If you are talking to the UI controls, use `Invoke` to get onto the UI thread earlier. You can of course query *external* data while on the background thread.

Comment: ok, blablabla = text.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => text.AppendText("test")));